# FadeOut and FadeIn before and after html load

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm working on a menu whose items loads a external HTML. I need a fadein or opacity effect before and after loads external HTML.
The load works fine, but not the transition effect between charges. It seems to work the first time I click on a menu item, but not the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {                         
$('#nav li').click(function () {
    var prod = $(this).children("a").attr('href');
    $(".contenido").fadeOut(500, function() {
          $(".contenido").load(prod);
    });
    $(".contenido").fadeIn(500);
   });
});
```

Comment: It might help people answering if you can give a bit more detail on what exactly is happening, and what you expect it to be happening. While I understand what you're asking, it took me quite a bit of time to actually get what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not calling fadeIn at the right time.  Put fadeIn in the callback function of load. I hope that is the problem you were having.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {                         
     $('#nav li').click(function () {
         var prod = $(this).children("a").attr('href');

         $(".contenido").fadeOut(500, function() {
             $(this).load(prod, function(){
                    $(this).fadeIn(500); //Fade In after load finishes
             });
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: This works in the same way like my code , only works on first load.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML I can't be sure but maybe it has to do with the .click event handler.  If you are clicking dynamic elements then .click() won't work. Try $(body).on("click","#nav li",function)

Comment: @cerilo just trying to get all the info. If you could give us some of your HTML,that would help. If you put alert boxes in the click and load callbacks to test what is firing and not firing, that will help. At first they will both fire but how many fire the second time?

Comment: Sorry James, your code is working now. I had an error in the html code, thanks for your answer!